# Webpack multiple named chunks ignoring names at runtime

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, amd, commonjs, webpack

I am having trouble with webpacks code splitting functionality. I am trying to have 2 named chunks for two routes in my application which are not often visited. mysite.com/settings and mysite.com/access.

here is my webpack.config.coffee

```
module.exports =

  contentBase: "#{__dirname}/src/"

  cache: true

  entry:
    app: './src/coffee/app'
    head: './src/coffee/head'

  output:
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
    publicPath: '/'
    filename: '[name].js'
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'

  plugins: []
```

And here is my router.coffee

```
access: (slug) ->

    _this = @
    require.ensure ['../view/page/access-page.coffee'], (require) ->
      AccessPage = require '../view/page/access-page.coffee'
      accessPage = AccessPage.getInstance()
      accessPage.render() unless accessPage.isRendered
      _this.showPage accessPage
    , 'access'


settings: (slug) ->

    _this = @
    require.ensure ['../view/page/settings-page.coffee'], (require) ->
      SettingsPage = require '../view/page/settings-page.coffee'
      settingsPage = SettingsPage.getInstance()
      settingsPage.render() unless settingsPage.isRendered
      _this.showPage settingsPage
    , 'settings'
```

I am not using the webpack dev-server, instead I am watching simply by using the following cmd-line tool

```
webpack -d --progress --colors --watch
```

The problem is that it ignores the names when requiring the files, as you can see the format is '[name]-[hash].js' it generates files with the correct format e.g. settings-2j3nekj2n3ejkn2.js but during development, when I attempt to load the page, the browser complains that '-2j3nekj2n3ejkn2.js' cannot be found, somehow the mapping of the files, ignores the names. If I leave out the names, then it works.

So the question is how can I setup mulitple named chunks correctly. Thanks in advance.

Note I have checked out their examples in the docs at https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/code-splitting

and I have followed their optimization docs aswell at
https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization

But I am stuck

Answer (score 2):

Well the simple answer is - [name= is not supported in chunkName.

The awesome guys at Webpack have actually heard my cries and implemented it

Here is the commit
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/03c87c11a4219ae6ec6bfe87e570a0dacceac859

As a result of the following issue I made
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/358

It is already available as of Beta ^1.3.2